# virtualenv wrapper custom directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How do I set the location for a certain virtual env in virtualenv wrapper?

I am happy for my existing and most of my future projects to still sit within

```
~/.virtualenv
```

but I want my web project virtual environment to sit within my web project folder.

Thanks

Comment: Why don you want to put the virtualenv folder inside your project folder? It's a bad practise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that wouldn't be possible. `virtualenvwrapper` is [hard-coded to follow `WORKON_HOME`](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/master/virtualenvwrapper.sh#cl-685) when searching for virtualenvs. There's no clean way to point a specific virtualenv to a certain location. The only workaround I can think of is `ln -s`-ing your virtualenv into `WORKON_HOME`, which is probably not what you're looking for.

But if you want to use a virtualenv placed in an arbitrary location, you can simply just use `virtualenv` directly. Obviously you lose hooks like `postactivate`, `predeactivate`, etc., but it's not impossible to replace these.

### Edit: Environment variable hack

One hack (as mentioned by James Mills), though, is to replace `WORKON_HOME` temporarily when you load the certain virtualenv. Just prefix you commands (`mkvirtualenv`, `workon`, etc.) with an environment variable override:

```
$ WORKON_HOME=/where/you/want mkvirtualenv virtualenv_name
```

And the virtualenv will be created in `/where/you/want`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the env var `WORKON_HOME`. e.g:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/var/env
```

You can set this in your `~/.bashrc`.

This is documented here: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: OP said he/she doesn't want to change the existing WORKON_HOME !

Comment: Doesn't matter. The process is still the same. Change the ``WORKON_HOME`` either permanently or temporarily.